# How to fix compile error using Eclipse C\C++

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, compilation

I have a simple program in C that references a custom header as follows

```
    #include "apue.h"
```

When building from Eclipse, I get error:

```
    undefined reference to `err_quit'
```

I know that if I compile outside of Eclipse using the terminal as follows, there is no error

```
    gcc -o lsf lsf.c -L /usr/local/lib -lapue
```

So how to tell Eclipse to use above compile switches that do work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've got your answer. Don't compile under Eclipse. Use the command line (and you should use `gcc -Wall -g lsf.c -L /usr/local/lib -lapue -o lsf`). Even better, use a good editor like `emacs`

Comment: Excellent thank you. Emacs is simpler and I like it. I'm sure Eclipse users have a way to solve this too.